# how to handle undefined methods during minitest controller testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, minitest

I have following methods in my contest model.

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions
  has_many :users, through: :submissions

  validates_presence_of :name, :admin_id

  acts_as_votable

  def admin_name
    User.find_by_id(self.admin_id).username
  end

  def tonnage
    self.submissions.sum(:tonnage)
  end

  def contest_type_tr
    I18n.t("contests.contest_type")[self.contest_type]
  end

  def contest_short_descr
    I18n.t("contests.contest_short_descr")[self.contest_type]
  end

end
```

When doing a test for the contest controller I get the following error:

**ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass**

Why is this and how can I fix it?

My specs (minitest) are available below.

```
require "test_helper"

describe ContestsController do
  let(:user) { users :default }
  let(:contest) { contests :one }

  it "gets index" do
    get :index
    value(response).must_be :success?
    value(assigns(:contests)).wont_be :nil?
  end

  it "gets new" do
    get :new
    value(response).must_be :success?
  end

  it "creates contest" do
    expect {
      post :create, contest: {  }
    }.must_change "Contest.count"

    must_redirect_to contest_path(assigns(:contest))
  end

  it "shows contest" do
    get :show, id: contest
    value(response).must_be :success?
  end

  it "gets edit" do
    get :edit, id: contest
    value(response).must_be :success?
  end

  it "updates contest" do
    put :update, id: contest, contest: {  }
    must_redirect_to contest_path(assigns(:contest))
  end

  it "destroys contest" do
    expect {
      delete :destroy, id: contest
    }.must_change "Contest.count", -1

    must_redirect_to contests_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Does the contest have a user? Also, why not just have a normal relation to the user instead of doing a `User.find` manually?

Comment: The contest has a user and is linked through submissions. I'll update with the complete model code. The contest admin is not the same person as the one doing a submission. Everybody can do submissions but I define the admin using a admin field. (if you can suggest a better way to do this relation feel free :) I am a newb. )

Comment: You can associate an admin through the same mechanism; check out the [Rails Association Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (too lazy to find the exact section, sorry). In any case, in this case, it seems like your admin user doesn't exist, that's why I asked about the contest having a user, but I meant an admin user--my fault I wasn't clear.

Comment: So if I understand it correct I got 2 options, fix the admin association using a new has_one association or create a admin user in the fixtures?

Comment: The contest would need an admin no matter how you do the association, whether manually as now, or via standard Rails associations. At least as the code stands now.